# Query about stochvol package in R

Tags: r, stochastic-processes

This is regarding the package stochvol in R.

[See vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stochvol/vignettes/article.pdf)

I am referring to section 3.1 of the above document. It says:-

The  core  sampling  function svsample
expects  its  input  data y to  be  a  numeric  vector  of
returns without any missing values ( NA s) and throws an error if provided with anything else.In  the  case  that
y contains  zeros,  a  warning  is  issued  and  a  small  offset  constant  of  size sd(y)/10000 is added to the squared returns before doing the auxiliary mixture sampling (cf.Omori et al. 2007).  **However, we generally recommend to avoid zero returns altogether, e.g.,by demeaning them beforehand.**

But then in the next few lines it does this :-

```
ret <- logret(exrates$USD, demean = TRUE)
```

My query is: Do we demean the returns or not and why does it recommend to avoid zero returns ?